# The reference to entity "size" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: java, html, jquery, freemarker

I don't understand what the problem might be, it gives the error [Fatal error] :94:69: The reference to the "size" object should end with a separator ';'.

```
<#macro pager url page>
    <#if page.getTotalPages() gt 7>
        <#assign
        totalPages = page.getTotalPages()
        pageNumber = page.getNumber() + 1

        head = (pageNumber > 4)?then([1, -1], [1, 2, 3])
        tail = (pageNumber < totalPages - 3)?then([-1, totalPages], [totalPages - 2, totalPages - 1, totalPages])
        bodyBefore = (pageNumber > 4 && pageNumber < totalPages - 1)?then([pageNumber - 2, pageNumber - 1], [])
        bodyAfter = (pageNumber > 2 && pageNumber < totalPages - 3)?then([pageNumber + 1, pageNumber + 2], [])

        body = head + bodyBefore + (pageNumber > 3 && pageNumber < totalPages - 2)?then([pageNumber], []) + bodyAfter + tail
        >
    <#else>
        <#assign body = 1..page.getTotalPages()>
    </#if>
    <div class="mt-3">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Страницы</a>
            </li>
            <#list body as p>
                <#if (p - 1) == page.getNumber()>
                    <li class="page-item active">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">${p}</a>
                    </li>
                <#elseif p == -1>
                    <li class="page-item disabled">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">...</a>
                    </li>
                <#else>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${p - 1}&size=${page.getSize()}" tabindex="-1">${p}</a>
                    </li>
                </#if>
            </#list>
        </ul>

        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Элементов на странице</a>
            </li>
            <#list [5, 10, 25, 50] as c>
                <#if c == page.getSize()>
                    <li class="page-item active">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">${c}</a>
                    </li>
                <#else>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${page.getNumber()}&size=${c}" tabindex="-1">${c}</a>
                    </li>
                </#if>
            </#list>
        </ul>
    </div>
</#macro>
```

```
import com.example.Sweater.controller.MessageController;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;

import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.response.SecurityMockMvcResultMatchers.authenticated;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.xpath;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
//@Sql(value = {"/create-user-before.sql", "/messages-list-before.sql"}, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
//@Sql(value = {"/messages-list-after.sql", "/create-user-after.sql"}, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
@WithUserDetails(value = "admin2")
public class MessageControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MessageController controller;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void mainPageTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/main"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(authenticated()) 
                .andExpect(xpath("//div[@id='navbarSupportedContent']/div").string("admin2"));
    }
```

These are two lines in which size is used----------->>>>>

```
  <a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${p - 1}&size=${page.getSize()}" tabindex="-1">${p}</a>
<a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${page.getNumber()}&size=${c}" tabindex="-1">${c}</a>
```

I noticed & on &amp, but it didn't help because it made me write the error [Fatal error] :94:69: The reference to the "ampsize" object should end with a separator ';'.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track and almost solved it. You need to replace `&size=` with `&amp;size=` (`&amp;` is the HTML entity for the "&" character).

Those two lines will then become:

```
  <a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${p - 1}&amp;size=${page.getSize()}" tabindex="-1">${p}</a>
  <a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${page.getNumber()}&amp;size=${c}" tabindex="-1">${c}</a>
```